# How to copy value form input to variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a Color picker on my website, which includes an input with the name "acf[field_65d8d325d69cb]". The value of this field changes dynamically depending on the selected color. I'm trying to make the dynamic value of this input assigned to the variable colorValue in the following code:

```
// Retrieve the input element based on its name
var inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="acf[field_65d8d325d69cb]"]');

// Check if the input element is found
if (inputElement) {
  // If found, assign the value to the variable colorValue
  var colorValue = inputElement.value;

  // Create a new style element
  var styleElement = document.createElement('style');

  // Set the CSS style content with the value from the input
  styleElement.textContent = '.editor-styles-wrapper { --theme-palette-color-10: ' + colorValue + ' !important; }';

  // Append the new style element to the head section of the document
  document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
} else {
  console.error('Input element not found.');
}
```

What I want to achieve is a dynamic change of the colorValue based on the selected color in the Color picker. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Listen to the `change` or `input` events of that input element, then change your styles accordingly

Comment: And ask yourself why you need to copy the value to a variable. Can't you just look at the value when you need it?

Comment: @ScottMarcus So, what specific solution are you proposing?

Comment: At the time somebody has selected the color. The variable declaration already run. As @Bergi said you MUST use an `addEventListener()`. 

Comment: When you need the value of the element, just get it directly from the color picker instead of taking the extra step of storing it in a variable **which will need to be updated every time a new color is chosen**.

Comment: Also, if your element is statically part of the DOM, then there is no need to check to see if it is found after referencing it by its ID.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Does it matter in this case that input[name="acf[field_65d8d325d69cb]"] is type="hidden"?

Comment: How is the input's value changing if it's hidden?

Comment: It is ACF's (WordPress plugin) color picker. This hidden input changes while selecting new colors, for example, in the spectrum.

Comment: So you have a WordPress color picker that transfers its value to a hidden element when a color is chosen in the picker? As long as the hidden element has the value you want, then no, it doesn't matter.

Comment: For test I want to display this value in console. Is this should work? var hiddenInput = document.querySelector('input[name="acf[field_65d8d325d69cb]"]');

if (hiddenInput) {
    hiddenInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var hiddenValue = hiddenInput.value;
        console.log(hiddenValue);
    });
}

Because it dose not...

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the input element, on change.

```js
const styleElement = document.querySelector('style[title="custom"]');

document.forms.form01['acf[field_65d8d325d69cb]'].addEventListener('change', e => {
  styleElement.textContent = `.editor-styles-wrapper {
      --theme-palette-color-10: ${e.target.value} !important;
    }`;
});
```

```css
.editor-styles-wrapper {
  background-color: var(--theme-palette-color-10);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style title="custom"></style>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form01">
    <input name="acf[field_65d8d325d69cb]" type="color">
  </form>
  <div class="editor-styles-wrapper">test</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

@chrwahl is right.

But If above answer does not work there is also another approach. I have not tested it but you can give it a try.

Now,Instead of directly reading the input value, attach an onchange event listener to the input element.
Within the event listener function, grab the new color value using inputElement.value.
Update the colorValue variable with the new value.
Use the updated colorValue to create the new style element and inject it into the head, as you already have in your code.
Here's an example:

```
// Retrieve the input element
var inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="acf[field_65d8d325d69cb]"]');

// Check if the input element is found
if (inputElement) {
  // Add an onchange event listener
  inputElement.onchange = function() {
    // Update the colorValue with the new value
    var colorValue = inputElement.value;

    // Create and inject the style element
    var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.textContent = '.editor-styles-wrapper { --theme-palette-color-10: ' + colorValue + ' !important; }';
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
  };
} else {
  console.error('Input element not found.');
}
```

Comment: This creates and adds a new style every time the input changes. This may work, but creates a memory leak - you should remove the previous style as well.

Comment: @Bergi you are right. Let me check that.